# Why don't some of the tiles on Windows 8 Start Screen have the "larger" choice?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

It seems like some of the app images on the Windows 8 start screen have a "Larger" button to show a rectangle bigger layout tile (compared to the square).  But I noticed that a number of apps don't have this option when I right click on the icon.  I can't see any pattern here.  Is there some logic why some app can be shown in the larger tile and some can only be shown in the square size ?

Answer (score 5):

> The default tile images also define the sizes that the tile supports.
> Tiles are available in two sizes: square or wide. All apps must
> support a square tile, but an app can also support a wide tile. **If an
> app doesn’t provide a wide logo image for the default tile, the app
> tile cannot be resized to a wide tile,** which means that it cannot
> receive a wide tile notification. If the app includes a wide logo
> image, Windows shows the tile in its wide format by default.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309190237/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/16/creating-a-great-tile-experience-part-1.aspx)

So basically, it's up to the app developer to implement this optional large tile mode.

Answer (score 1):

Only "metro" apps, apps that support the metro interface have that options. So most apps you download from the Store will have that.

On the other hand, traditional desktop application that are not gear towards the mobile interface, do not support the metro interface, will only show a enlarged icon.

---

*Update after discussion with ioSamurai*

Additionally, just as ioSamurai pointed out in his answer, "metro" app may or may not support the large tile style. That is completely a developer choice.

Comment: Down vote for what reason?

Comment: Your information is inaccurate.

Comment: How inaccurate? The link in your answer is actually for metro style design (web store app).

Comment: You said: 'Only "metro" apps, apps that support the metro interface have that options.' which is not true, it is possible for a metro app to NOT support a large tile. Your answer also isn't answering his question, which is 'why don't all of the tiles support large tile view?'

Comment: apps not supporting metro will not have that feature at all, large tile view is a metro feature. No metro, no large tile.

Comment: Correct, but that's not the whole picture, it's possible that a metro app will also not have that feature! Also, that doesn't answer his question as to why the METRO app sometimes doesn't support the feature.

Comment: OP didn't mention about app store only app or other app in a desktop setup. We don't even know if OP is using a tablet or a desktop. All we know is Windows 8. My answer focus on difference between traditional desktop app and metro app. Yours only mention metro apps. I would say both our answers are incomplete.

Comment: I updated my answer to make it "complete".